# Program type already present: android.support.v7.app.ActionBar$LayoutParams

Tags: android

I imported lib for ActionBarActivity Successfully but when i build my project,
it is getting the following error help me.

```
Compilation failed to complete
```

Error:

```
    Program type already present: android.support.v7.app.ActionBar$LayoutParams
Message{kind=ERROR, text=Program type already present: android.support.v7.app.ActionBar$LayoutParams, sources=[Unknown source file], tool name=Optional.of(D8)}
```

And This is my Gradle File Code:

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 27
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.hsdsolution.hamza.sqliteimplementation"
        minSdkVersion 14
        targetSdkVersion 27
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
        testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
}

dependencies {
    implementation fileTree(include: ['*.jar'], dir: 'libs')
    implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:27.1.1'
   // implementation 'com.android.support:design:27.1.1'
    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
    androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test:runner:1.0.2'
    androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.0.2'
    implementation files('libs/android-support-v4.jar')
    implementation files('libs/android-support-v7-appcompat.jar')
}
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Android build error: Program type already present: android.support.v7.app.\*\*](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51902287/android-build-error-program-type-already-present-android-support-v7-app)

Answer (score 0):

you are adding the dependency for `appcompat-v7` three times ...

```
implementation fileTree(include: ['*.jar'], dir: 'libs')
implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:27.1.1'
// implementation files('libs/android-support-v7-appcompat.jar')
```

delete file `libs/android-support-v7-appcompat.jar` and it should build.

Comment: i removed but now this error is occur on java file

'import android.support.v7.app.ActionBarActivity;'

Comment: @hamza `com.android.support:appcompat-v7:27.1.1` should provide it; sync your project to let it download the jars.

Comment: No still same error : import android.support.v7.app.ActionBarActivity;